# Regex code is not working

Tags: php, regex

is this regex code working? For example, i want to find a text like:

```
|||xxx|||
```

where xxx will be a number

i want to use it with curl php, so i can scrape a https page and get just the numbers inside the pipes

```
$regex = '~\|{3}(\d+)\|{3}~';   //is this correct
if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) ){
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: But you might want `preg_match_all` instead?

Answer (score -1):

If xxx in your example will only ever be numbers and with no additional formatting, I don't see why that wouldn't work. Might be easier for you to just test against what you're actually trying to scrape though.

This is a basic example if you're just looking for a way to test though: https://regex101.com/r/uJjByK/1